# Where I can found the default schema code in shopify?

Tags: seo, schema, shopify, shopify-template

Where I can found the default schema code in shopify?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "reviewCount": "2",
        "ratingValue": "5.0",
        "itemReviewed": {
          "@type" : "Product",
          "name" : "Cuisinart Automatic Bread Maker",
          "offers": {
            "@type": "AggregateOffer",
            "lowPrice": "125.0",
            "highPrice": "125.0",
            "priceCurrency": "CAD"
          }
        }
      }
</script>
```

This code actually visible after html tag. Need help. Screenshot attached[image: Structured data screenshot]

Comment: Which theme is used on Shopifyy shop?

Comment: `Empire v4.6.0`

Comment: Might be there is any APP that adds the same, check the same into APP and theme.liquid into very end, is there is any snippet added to regarding it?

Comment: Abandoned Cart Recovery,Constant Contact
Events Calendar
Facebook
Frequently Bought Together
Google
Lookalike Audience Builder
Matrixify (Excelify)
Metafields Guru
OxenBytes - Dimensions
Custom
Product Reviews
Purolator
Shippo Logo
Shippo
Shopify Email Logo
Shopify Email
Smart Spin To Win Logo
Smart Spin To Win
SPO (SEO Product Optimizer) Logo
SPO (SEO Product Optimizer)
Store Locator Logo
Store Locator
Theme Updater Logo
Theme Updater
Zendesk Logo
Zendesk
Zendesk-Chat Logo
Zendesk-Chat

Comment: Hmm, are you able to share the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the above mentioned schema not visible in latest version of structured data. Checked and confirmed.